# Acessar conteúdo de outro projeto na mesma Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, diretório

O caso é o seguinte: Tenho uma *Solution* com dois Projetos, um Administrativo e outro um WebSite, ambos utilizando C# e MVC4.

No primeiro projeto eu salvo imagens e arquivos em uma pasta `Documents`, e ao acessar o WebSite gostaria de acessar o conteúdo desta pasta. Entendo que a *Solution* deve ter um diretório virtual e que eu devo configurá-lo ao hospedar a minha aplicação e o site, mas não sei como posso simular isso enquanto ainda os mesmos não estão hospedados.

Até já usei `@Url.Content("~/Documents/"+cliente.Imagem)` mas sem sucesso. Creio que não estou compreendendo o cenário por completo e/ou como devo prepará-lo

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa acessar o endereço físico da pasta onde está salvando os documentos... Se sua aplicação (website) tiver permissão de acesso para a pasta física que você armazena os documentos é só seguir com a vida...

Comment: No caso Endereço físico completo como abaixo?
C:\Users\VICTOR\Solution\Admin\Documents\[nome do documento]?

Comment: Se é nesta pasta que guarda os documentos, sim.

Comment: Olá, tentei o caminho físico como sugerido, a pasta está com permissão.Porém a imagem ainda não consegue ser encontrada.
Já tentei com Barras e com Contra-barras tbm, mas nenhuma delas com sucesso.
Tem algum LINK de exemplo para eu ter certeza que não estou errando no caminho?
Obrigado

Comment: Veja bem, não há mágica: são arquivos numa pasta, apenas isso. Por exemplo, quando você adiciona um arquivo na pasta c:\imagens, lá estarão as imagens e você pode acessá-las de qualquer lugar desde que tenha acesso/permissão. Antes de qualquer coisa, consegue ir até a pasta e verificar se as imagens realmente estão lá? O segundo passo, confirmado o primeiro, seria acessar todos os arquivos da pasta via código, para ver se o usuário que está rodando a aplicação realmente tem permissão para visualizar os arquivos. Se sim, seja feliz, caso contrário acredito que seja permissão ou o código...

Comment: esse `cliente.imagem` vem com a extensão do arquivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A abordagem correta seria criar, no site administrativo, uma interface adequada para servir as imagens.

Para isso, crie um *Controller* chamado `ImagensController`. Dentro dele implemente a seguinte *Action*:

```
public FileResult Imagem(int id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var imagem = db.Imagens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ImagemId == id);
        if (imagem != null)
        {
            var arquivoDeImagem = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/galeria/" + imagem.imagem);
            return File(arquivoDeImagem, "image/jpeg");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Uso:

```
<img src="http://siteadministrativo/Imagens/Imagem/5" alt="@item.nome" />
```

Note que este método utiliza um cadastro de imagens dentro do seu módulo administrativo, pois selecionamos o cadastro de uma imagem num contexto de dados (`db`).

Ainda, se você quiser deixar a configuração bem dinâmica, pode usar uma URL configurável no seu `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://localhost:15829/" />
    ...
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Para acessar o valor na *View*, você pode implementar um *Helper*:

```
public static class ConfigurationHelper
{
    public static String BaseUrl()
    {
        var baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
        return baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Aí fica:

```
<img src="@(ConfigurationHelper.BaseUrl() + "/Imagens/Imagem/5")" alt="@item.nome" />
```

Por fim, você pode usar [arquivos de transformação](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301874) e configurar a troca da URL no momento da publicação:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseURL" value="http://meusite.com.br" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Obrigado mesmo, sua resposta deixou meu código bem mais enxuto, além de aprender de uma forma melhor.
Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que subir os dois projetos ao mesmo tempo, ou seja, os dois tem que estar "Online". 
Sua referência a imagen deve ser a url completa exemplo: h t t p: //localhost:8455/Content/imagen01.jpg

para acessar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso não exatamente resolve o problema que o autor da pergunta tem, mas é uma ótima dica. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Senhores, muito obrigado pela ajuda de vocês, descobri a solução e creio que possa ajudar a muitos.
O que eu fiz foi Executar o administrativo primeiro, assim ele "Simulava um servidor como http://localhost:55191/.....
Então Inseri o caminho completo da imagem, incluido o localhost + porta e deu certo, olhe no exemplo exemplo:
@Url.Content("http://localhost:55191/Conteudo/"+item.Imagem)
Acessei o conteúdo acima através da seguinte URL: 
http://localhost:51871/Home/Index
Obrigado novamente pela força!!!

Comment: Essa solução não é boa, até porque se você publicar os dois sites em outro lugar, não vai funcionar.

Comment: Poxa meu camarada, foi para fins de testes, pois quando eu criar um diretório virtual na minha hospedagem não terei mas esse problema.
Mas caso tenha uma sugestão melhor poderia me informar?

Comment: Tenho. Posso colocar como resposta, se quiser. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho, mas fica mais correta e mais robusta.

Comment: Claro, fique a vontade.
Qualquer coisa eu mudo o Check para a sua :D